# Multiple innner joins with Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, inner-join

I have tables like this.

`Title` table:

```
Book_Title        | ISBN    |Publisher_ID
--------------------------------------
Engineering BK    | 1234556 | 1
Time for a change | 1233333 | 2
Digital Fortress  | 2132312 | 3
Davinci Code      | 2314234 | 3
Angles and Demons | 1232323 | 3
```

Book ISBN is not normal ISBN it's  of `int` type.

`Copy` table:

```
   Copy_ID   | ISBN 
-----------------------
      1      | 1234556
      2      | 1233333
      3      | 2132312
      4      | 2314234
      5      | 1232323
      6      | 1232323
```

`Loan` table:

```
Borrower_ID   | Copy_ID | Date_Borrowed |Date_Returned
------------------------------------------------------
     1        |   1     |  2014-10-20   | NULL
     2        |   2     |  2014-10-18   | NULL
     3        |   3     |  2014-10-11   | 2014-10-20
     1        |   4     |  2011-11-11   | 2011-11-25
     2        |   5     |  2010-10-10   | NULL
     4        |   6     |  2012-12-12   | NULL
```

Status of the books which are not returned yet are SAVED as NULL.

I want to select all the titles in which all the copies are borrowed and still has not returned.
In other words Titles which are having all the copies borrowed in the Loan table with Date_Returned as NULL.

I'm trying to do it like this.

```
     SELECT DISTINCT(T.Book_Title) AS BookTitle
     FROM Title T
     INNER JOIN Copy CP ON T.ISBN=CP.ISBN
     INNER JOIN Loan LN ON CP.Copy_ID=LN.Copy_ID
     WHERE (SELECT COUNT (CP.Copy_ID) FROM Title T
     INNER JOIN Copy CP ON T.ISBN=CP.ISBN WHERE T.Book_Title=''
    )
    =
    (SELECT COUNT (CP.Copy_ID)FROM Title T INNER JOIN Copy CP ON T.ISBN=CP.ISBN
     INNER JOIN Loan LN ON CP.Copy_ID=LN.Copy_ID
     WHERE LN.Date_Returned IS NULL AND T.Book_Title='')
    GROUP BY T.Book_Title
```

But in this I have to mention book titles by name in each sub query. But I need to check for all the titles in the Titles.

How to solve this? Any help would be really great.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT a.ISBN
FROM   (SELECT ISBN,Count(Copy_ID) cnt
        FROM   Copy
        GROUP  BY ISBN) A
       JOIN (SELECT c.isbn,Count(c.copy_id) cnt
             FROM   copy c
                    JOIN Loan L
                      ON c.copy_id = l.copy_id
             WHERE  l.Date_Returned IS NULL
             Group by c.isbn) b
         ON a.ISBN = B.ISBN
            AND a.cnt = b.cnt
       JOIN title t
         ON t.ISBN = A.ISBN
```

Comment: Thanks it works. If you don't mind can you add a little explanation on what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT T.Book_Title
 FROM Title T
 INNER JOIN Copy CP ON T.ISBN=CP.ISBN
 LEFT JOIN Loan LN ON CP.Copy_ID=LN.Copy_ID
 GROUP BY T.Book_Title
 HAVING sum(case when LN.Copy_ID is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
 AND sum(case when LN.Date_Returned IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: NO It doesn't give any out put though I have data in my tables.